# DC power connections

Tags: dc, led-driver

I am building a fixture out of LEDs (COBs to be exact) and I'd like to use a 4 prong twistlock AC power plug for a DC connection.

I know this is not recommended but hear me out.

My drivers for the LED'S and the fan are mounted remotely (about 10 feet from the array) and the series of LED'S runs at 300v x 500mA DC.  I'd like to be able to run the power cord from the driver to the array and then use a heavy-duty connector rated for 300v in a junction box on top of the array.  Every "quick connect" dc connector I've seen either looks flimsy or isn't rated for 300v.  The appeal of the 4 prong twistlock (to this relative novice) is that it's really sturdy and can house both the LED power and fan power in the same cord/connection.

Right now I'm using wagos in a small junction box on top of the array but it would be nice to be able to unplug and move the thing without having to open up the JB and snap off the connectors.

So, am I going to burn my house down?  Are there beefy DC connectors  (like a twistlock) that I'm just missing?  Is using 2 of the wires in the cord to connect to a 12v fan, and the other two to connect to a 300v string of LEDS a terrible idea?

Thanks for reading this, I really appreciate any guidance!

Comment: Can you get the finger-proof Anderson Powerpoles where you're at?  The [datasheet](http://www.mouser.com/ds/2/22/ds-pp1545-766098.pdf) lists them as good out to 600V...

Answer (score 3):

I'll leave others to comment on suitable connectors **BUT**

**DO NOT** unplug highish-voltage DC connectors with the system live.
DC can draw a really really really really nasty arc - how nasty you may never get to believe if you try it. I can arc weld (with a rather modest arc) from a 250  Watt, 30Vmp solar panel! At 300V with 500 mA+ available the arc may be more impressive than you'd hope.

A friend of a friend disconnected an N00V solar panel connector under bright sun conditions. He survived but ended up in hospital. (He had some kW available but your 150 Watts+ is not unimpressive.

I'd also be very wary of running the 12V and 300V together in a DC highish-V system. It should work just fine [tm] but on the day it doesn't the fan circuit may trivially easily become part of the 300V circuit by way initially of arc and soon thereafter via carbon tracking.
Ask me how I know :-).
I've experienced occasional incidents over decades, but relatively recently, a 3 kV isolated Hall current sensor had an in-IC 50A shunt. A battery short circuit of a 40 Ah LiFePO4 battery caused the Hall shunt to go O/C, and arc formed, the plastic IC housing carbonised and the 24V current entered the LV system. The 3 kV initial isolation counted for nothing. 
Your 300V would be unhealthy for 12V fans, low voltage wiring and people in immediate contact.